# JavaScript functions - Custom widget - Appcelerator alloy

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-modules

I have some issue while designing a custom js widget,here is the code

```
function SomeCustomWidget() {
    //private variables
    var referenceOfThis = this;
    var sideMenuWidth = 200;
    var selectedBgColor = '#8EBA04';

    function createWidget(){
        var containerView = //initialization
        var upperPartOfView = createUpperPartOfWidget();
        Ti.API.info("LOG2  This log is not getting printed");
        containerView.add(upperPartOfView);
        var lowerPartOfView = createLowerPartOfWidget();
        containerView.add(lowerPartOfView);
    }


    //Private methods
    function createUpperPartOfWidget(e) {
        var widgetUpperPart = //initialization codehere
        Ti.API.info("LOG1  This log is getting printed");
        return widgetUpperPart;
    }

    function createLowerPartOfWidget(e) {
        var widgetLowerPart = //initialization codehere
        return widgetLowerPart;
    }

    //Previlage method
    this.highlightWidget = function(e) {
        //access private variables and does somestuff
    };
}
module.exports = SomeCustomWidget;
```

I have few questions

1. Is the private methods inside constructor are automatically executed,`createWidget` in my case

2.Code after a call to privare function is not getting executed, (In my case `LOG1` is getting printed and `LOG2` doesn't, Is there any mistake in code)

Is this the correct approach to create a custom view,Please suggest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're talking about Alloy and Widgets, but the code you show is a CommonJS module and not https://appcelerator.github.io/appc-docs/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Widgets

No, when you call `SomeCustomWidget()` or do `new SomeCustomWidget()` JS won't run `createWidget()` by itself.

Comment: actually i was designing a side menu, is this the correct way to implement it ?, I am sending callback functions as a parameter to this common js, Is this a correct way

Comment: Well, not the correct way for a widget (see linked guide), but you can use classic JS in Alloy without any problem if you like. Did you check http://gitt.io/search?q=menu to see if there's isn't already a module, widget or library that does what you need?

Comment: Thanks @Fokke , will follow the Common JS for now.